# Tiny white squres when accesing yahoo mail via firefox in ubuntu

Tags: firefox, video

When logging into Y! mail the screen is populated with tiny white squares, also when watching facebook videos the squares also appear only this time they are not white but coloured.

I have no idea what might be causing this.

Comment: It may be helpful if you could post a screenshot of this happening.

Comment: I am trying to do it now

Comment: Sharing with you my e-mails and the video is here [link](https://youtu.be/nQvB9WdmYsM)